# Existe una sola función en R que me permita realizar un diagnóstico de todos los supuestos de un análisis de regresión lineal?

Tags: r

Existe una sola función en R que me permita realizar un diagnóstico de todos los supuestos de un análisis de regresión lineal? Me gustaría ver como la normalidad de los residuos, heterocedasticidad, homogeneidad de varianzas etc.

Muchas gracias